# Access last element in a list within a tibble

Tags: r, list, tibble

I extracted data from a pdf using keyword_search, which ended up summarizing the results in a tibble. Which is great, but now I want to further summarize the data that has been stored in the "token_text" list of the tibble, I am especially only interested in the last element of the list of each row. However, the functions that I know how to extract elements in a list do not seem to work in a tibble?

E.g. if I have a list element "a", then I can access the last element in that list with:

```
sapply(a,tail,1)
```

however this does not seem to work in the tibble:

```
result$token_text, tail,1)
```

As this only gives me the whole list and not the last element of the list.
What am I missing?

Below is a dput of my "result" tibble.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
structure(list(keyword = c("124-38-9", "124-38-9", "124-38-9", 
"124-38-9", "124-38-9", "124-38-9", "124-38-9", "124-38-9", "124-38-9", 
"124-38-9", "124-38-9", "124-38-9", "124-38-9", "124-38-9", "74-82-8", 
"74-82-8", "74-82-8", "74-82-8", "74-82-8", "74-82-8", "74-82-8", 
"74-82-8", "74-82-8", "74-82-8", "10024-97-2", "10024-97-2", 
"10024-97-2", "10024-97-2", "10024-97-2", "10024-97-2", "10024-97-2", 
"10024-97-2", "10024-97-2", "10024-97-2"), page_num = c(20L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 
22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L), line_num = c(500L, 503L, 
504L, 516L, 517L, 518L, 527L, 533L, 542L, 550L, 559L, 567L, 573L, 
579L, 505L, 519L, 528L, 534L, 545L, 551L, 560L, 568L, 574L, 580L, 
506L, 520L, 529L, 535L, 546L, 552L, 561L, 569L, 575L, 581L), 
    line_text = list("124-38-9                         CO2 nonbio             8812.3593                8812.3593", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2 bio-nC   0                     0", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2 bio-C    0                     0", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2 nonbio   0                     0", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2 bio-nC   0                     0", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2 bio-C    0                     0", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2  8411.7989              8411.7989", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2  0                      0", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2  392.9536               392.9536", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2  4.0087                 4.0087", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2  3.5981                 3.5981", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2 0                      0", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2 0                      0", 
        "124-38-9                         CO2 0                      0", 
        "74-82-8                          CH4          83.0642               2076.6050", 
        "74-82-8                          CH4          0                     0", 
        "74-82-8                          CH4  7.8340                 195.8500", 
        "74-82-8                          CH4  0                      0", 
        "74-82-8                          CH4  2.0398                 50.9950", 
        "74-82-8                          CH4  30.4243                760.6075", 
        "74-82-8                          CH4  42.7661                1069.1525", 
        "74-82-8                          CH4 0                      0", 
        "74-82-8                          CH4 0                      0", 
        "74-82-8                          CH4 0                      0", 
        "10024-97-2                       N2O          0.2146                63.9508", 
        "10024-97-2                       N2O          0                     0", 
        "10024-97-2                       N2O  0.2139                 63.7422", 
        "10024-97-2                       N2O  0                      0", 
        "10024-97-2                       N2O  0.0007                 0.2086", 
        "10024-97-2                       N2O  0                      0", 
        "10024-97-2                       N2O  0                      0", 
        "10024-97-2                       N2O 0                      0", 
        "10024-97-2                       N2O 0                      0", 
        "10024-97-2                       N2O 0                      0"), 
    token_text = list(list(c("124", "38", "9", "co2", "nonbio", 
    "8812.3593", "8812.3593")), list(c("124", "38", "9", "co2", 
    "bio", "nc", "0", "0")), list(c("124", "38", "9", "co2", 
    "bio", "c", "0", "0")), list(c("124", "38", "9", "co2", "nonbio", 
    "0", "0")), list(c("124", "38", "9", "co2", "bio", "nc", 
    "0", "0")), list(c("124", "38", "9", "co2", "bio", "c", "0", 
    "0")), list(c("124", "38", "9", "co2", "8411.7989", "8411.7989"
    )), list(c("124", "38", "9", "co2", "0", "0")), list(c("124", 
    "38", "9", "co2", "392.9536", "392.9536")), list(c("124", 
    "38", "9", "co2", "4.0087", "4.0087")), list(c("124", "38", 
    "9", "co2", "3.5981", "3.5981")), list(c("124", "38", "9", 
    "co2", "0", "0")), list(c("124", "38", "9", "co2", "0", "0"
    )), list(c("124", "38", "9", "co2", "0", "0")), list(c("74", 
    "82", "8", "ch4", "83.0642", "2076.6050")), list(c("74", 
    "82", "8", "ch4", "0", "0")), list(c("74", "82", "8", "ch4", 
    "7.8340", "195.8500")), list(c("74", "82", "8", "ch4", "0", 
    "0")), list(c("74", "82", "8", "ch4", "2.0398", "50.9950"
    )), list(c("74", "82", "8", "ch4", "30.4243", "760.6075")), 
        list(c("74", "82", "8", "ch4", "42.7661", "1069.1525"
        )), list(c("74", "82", "8", "ch4", "0", "0")), list(c("74", 
        "82", "8", "ch4", "0", "0")), list(c("74", "82", "8", 
        "ch4", "0", "0")), list(c("10024", "97", "2", "n2o", 
        "0.2146", "63.9508")), list(c("10024", "97", "2", "n2o", 
        "0", "0")), list(c("10024", "97", "2", "n2o", "0.2139", 
        "63.7422")), list(c("10024", "97", "2", "n2o", "0", "0"
        )), list(c("10024", "97", "2", "n2o", "0.0007", "0.2086"
        )), list(c("10024", "97", "2", "n2o", "0", "0")), list(
            c("10024", "97", "2", "n2o", "0", "0")), list(c("10024", 
        "97", "2", "n2o", "0", "0")), list(c("10024", "97", "2", 
        "n2o", "0", "0")), list(c("10024", "97", "2", "n2o", 
        "0", "0")))), row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: wow big data dump. it’s always appreciated if one tries to reduce the sample data to the necessary bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the following...

```
result$last_token <- sapply(result$token_text, function(x) tail(x[[1]], 1))
```

You need to `sapply` along the list of lists and do them one at a time.  This assumes that each element of `last_token` is a list of length 1 containing a vector.

Answer (score 1):

`token_text` is a list column, so you need to access the list element with `[[` further. Here is the solution using `map_chr` from `purrr`.

```
library(purrr)

map_chr(result$token_text, ~tail(.[[1]], 1)) 
# [1] "8812.3593" "0"         "0"         "0"         "0"         "0"        
# [7] "8411.7989" "0"         "392.9536"  "4.0087"    "3.5981"    "0"        
# [13] "0"         "0"         "2076.6050" "0"         "195.8500"  "0"        
# [19] "50.9950"   "760.6075"  "1069.1525" "0"         "0"         "0"        
# [25] "63.9508"   "0"         "63.7422"   "0"         "0.2086"    "0"        
# [31] "0"         "0"         "0"         "0"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with(result, sapply(token_text, function(x) tail(x[[1]], 1)))

[1] "8812.3593" "0"         "0"         "0"         "0"         "0"        
 [7] "8411.7989" "0"         "392.9536"  "4.0087"    "3.5981"    "0"        
[13] "0"         "0"         "2076.6050" "0"         "195.8500"  "0"        
[19] "50.9950"   "760.6075"  "1069.1525" "0"         "0"         "0"        
[25] "63.9508"   "0"         "63.7422"   "0"         "0.2086"    "0"        
[31] "0"         "0"         "0"         "0"
```

Or more `tidyverse`ish:

```
library(dplyr)
result %>% 
  pull(token_text) %>% 
  sapply(function(x) last(unlist(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse` I would do it this way :

```
result %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(token_text), ~map_chr(.,~last(.[[1]])))
# A tibble: 34 x 5
#     keyword page_num line_num line_text token_text
#       <chr>    <int>    <int>    <list>      <chr>
#  1 124-38-9       20      500 <chr [1]>  8812.3593
#  2 124-38-9       21      503 <chr [1]>          0
#  3 124-38-9       21      504 <chr [1]>          0
#  4 124-38-9       21      516 <chr [1]>          0
#  5 124-38-9       21      517 <chr [1]>          0
#  6 124-38-9       21      518 <chr [1]>          0
#  7 124-38-9       22      527 <chr [1]>  8411.7989
#  8 124-38-9       22      533 <chr [1]>          0
#  9 124-38-9       22      542 <chr [1]>   392.9536
# 10 124-38-9       23      550 <chr [1]>     4.0087
# ... with 24 more rows
```

and add a `%>% pull(token_text)` if you just want the content of the `token` column.